# Change color of text on parts of UILabel that are surrounded by asterisks

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string such as the following:

```
let myString = "This is my *awesome* label which *should* change color";
```

What I need to do is add this text to a UILabel, changing the text color to orange where the parts of the text are surrounded by asterisks, and removing the asterisks before displaying.

How can I accomplish this?

I know you can combine different colors of text using attributed text for labels, but not sure how to break up the string to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: Write an extension to String that defines a function markedAsOrange() that returns an AttributedString. Have it search for ranges of characters that are enclosed with asterisks and map them to orange attributed text ranges (after removing the asterisks in the result string.)

Comment: `"not sure how to break up the string"`. Try this: `myString.split(separator: "*")`.

Comment: Yeah but how can I tell which parts of the string are supposed to be orange?

Comment: This [article](https://medium.com/makingtuenti/writing-a-lightweight-markup-parser-in-swift-5c8a5f0f793f) may help you achieve that. It describes how to implement a lightweight Markup Language parser in Swift; which is very similar to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, that article did help me.

Comment: @codeman Well the **`bold`** text and the `non-bold` text will alternate, so you can do it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[\\*]{1}[^\\*]+[\\*]{1}")
```

`regex` is a regular expression that matches:

- One asterisk: `[\\*]{1}`. Followed by,
- One or more characters that are not an asterisk: `[^\\*]+`. Followed by,
- One asterisk: `[\\*]{1}`

Let's get the matches:

```
let str = "This is my *awesome* label which *should* change color"
let length = (str as NSString).length
let rg = NSRange(location: 0, length: length)
let matches = regex.matches(in: str, range: rg)
let ranges = matches.map {$0.range}
```

Let's create a mutable attributed string:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
```

And add the `foregroundColor` attribute to the matches, and remove the asterisks:

```
let attribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.orange]
let startIndex = str.startIndex
ranges.reversed()
    .forEach{ range in
        attributedString.addAttributes(attribute, range: range)
        let start = str.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound.advanced(by: 1))
        let end = str.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound.advanced(by: -1))
        let withoutAsterisk = String(str[start..<end])
        attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: range, with: withoutAsterisk)
}
```

And set the `attributedText` of your label

```
label.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Nice bit of work (voted), although I'm more inclined to outline a solution and give some of the pieces rather than providing a fully coded solution.